# Key navigation in caph 3

Tags: jquery, tizen, samsung-smart-tv, caph-framework

I am working on an application for samsung tv using caph 3 and jquery. I am getting this error in console.

```
 Uncaught TypeError: $.caph.focus.init is not a function
```

code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.caph.focus.init(function(nearestFocusableFinderProvider, controllerProvider) {
        // Not Working
    });
 });
```

While other functions are working fine like this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
 $.caph.focus.activate(function(nearestFocusableFinderProvider, controllerProvider) {  
        // working
    });
});
```

I would like to thank you if someone suggest me why am I getting this error. I have googled but no luck.

Thank you

Comment: Please post the code snippet so that we can have a look at it.

Comment: $.caph.focus.init(function(nearestFocusableFinderProvider, controllerProvider) {    
});

Comment: We would need see more code, one line of code won't help.

Comment: plz check my question. I have update my code

Comment: I need to see a complete code snippet. Please provide us with more code, other than the line where you are calling the init function.